# Partial discharge of capacitors - can it be engineered to give a desired, continuous output?

Tags: capacitance

Don't know anything about physics.  I expect to be ignored or told to go somewhere else.

My question is on converting energy stored in a capacitor by engineering controlled partial discharge (leakage, etc) as an intended function of the system.  I don't want to go too deep into my own thoughts on the issue

Can it be done? Is there anywhere I can go to see what is being done with it?

It seems to me that capacity, with all the nano-tech coming out, will not be a hindrance to using supercapacitors as energy storage in the near-term.  I would think energy lost through conversion would be a bigger issue.  Tell me if I'm misguided please, and I'll move on.

Comment: *"My question is on converting energy stored in a capacitor by engineering controlled partial discharge (leakage, etc) as an intended function of the system."* - Converted to what form?  Energy stored in a capacitor is routinely converted to another form by 'controlled partial discharge' by intentional design.  Do you have something novel in mind?

Comment: Maybe just misinformed, but not novel.  It's my understanding that capacitors discharge in a short amount of time, and that it looks like a diminishing burst of electricity.  So, if I have a capacitor, it fills up, and discharges, then fills up, then discharges in bursts.  I was thinking of a way to build dynamic pathways for partial discharge to "steal and route" a constant stream of energy from a capacitor as a function of its total charge at the moment.

Comment: William, whatever it is you have in mind, does it conserve energy or not?

Comment: Yes - it would conserve energy.

Comment: I mean, the energy taken from the capacitor would no longer be in the capacitor, but the output of the system would be as close as possible to the amount taken from the capacitor... I'll read more before commenting or posting on here in the future.  I don't know the foundations, so sorry for that.

Comment: How?  How would a capacitor deliver a *constant* stream of energy while conserving energy?